# how to hide remove subView on button click in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, window, subview

I have iphone application in which i am adding subView to window it works fine but i want that when i press close button it should hide the subView here is the code i ma doing for creating subView

```
 UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 1024,768)];
 subView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgPopupback.png"]];
 UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
 if (!window) 
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
 [[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:subView];
```

Close Button Action

```
   -(void)closeButtonAction{



   NSLog(@"CLicked on this button");

  [subView removeFromSuperview] ; 

  self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;

  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove your `subView` using `removeFromSuperview` and if you just want to hide your subview means use `subView.hidden = YES;` inside your button action

Answer (score 3):

**Remove your view**

```
[yourView removeFromSuperview];
```

**Hide your view**

```
[yourView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: it does not hide in this way i have tested this line

Comment: wokred thanks actually it was subView declaration confilict with other same name variable thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to hide your sub-view then in your -(void)closeButtonAction method do like this

```
-(void)closeButtonAction{



   NSLog(@"CLicked on this button");

  //[subView removeFromSuperview] ; 

  subView.alpha = 0;

  self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;

  }
```

Comment: i also have the same issue ,but  it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
viewDidLoad()
{
UIButton *m_btnSample = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [m_btnSample setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 200, 40)];
    [m_btnSample setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley1.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [m_btnSample addTarget:self action:@selector(btnChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:m_btnSample];
}

 -(void)btnChanged
    {
        [viewYouWantToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

Comment: ok then i suppose better is to hide the view when btn is clicked